# Angular $resource save an object containing arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rest

Let's say we have a `Person` $resource that looks like this:

```
$scope.person = {
  name: 'Max',
  friends: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

If we `Person.save($scope.person)` to server, it would send the following parameters:

```
name: 'Max'
friends: '1'
friends: '2'
friends: '3'
```

So I will not have access to the array of `friends` on the server. Only its last element would be accessible.

What is the correct way of saving objects containing arrays to server using `$resource`?

---

*p.s. I'm aware of a really hacky way, which is renaming `friends` attribute to `friends[]`, but that's not solving my problem, as I have a lot of these and I can't go with redefining properties back and forth*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

`non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])`

So you have to use:

```
Person.save(null, $scope.person)
```

(first argument is object with url params, second is data to send)

Then your friends array will be available in request body.

Note also that if you have person resource, you can do:

```
var person = $resource(...);
person.name = 'john';
person.friends = ['friend1' ,'friend2'];
person.$save();
```